# Is it better to convert ZonedDateTime to Long instead for better comparison performance?

Tags: java, performance, java-8, java-time, zoneddatetime

In my Java code, there are a lot of places where two `ZonedDateTime` objects will be compared to see which is later or earlier than the other.

My question here is whether there is a better performance impact if I convert those `ZonedDateTime` objects to Long earlier on and let the comparisons happen between `Long` objects instead of `ZonedDateTime`?

Is the performance gain negligible?

Comment: `there are a lot of places where two ZonedDateTime objects will be compared ` - that is not really important. Comparing two dates of any format will take a small amout of time. There is no need to micro optimize code unless you have a problem. For example if you compare 1000's of dates at one time you might try to optimize, but don't bother for a single comparison. And if you really want to know then write a test case for yourself and see which is more efficient.

Comment: It is most commonly true that asking about optimizations such as this before you even know that you have a performance problem is unwise.  It is certainly possible that these comparisons represent only a few percentage points of the total execution time of your system and, in such a case, even a significant optimization would realize little net performance impact.  You need to profile your system to know that you have a problem before you devote resources to solving it.

Comment: Don’t worry until you know you are having a performance problem. If in doubt, conduct tests do determine whether you have. I doubt that you can do anything smarter than `ZonedDateTime.isBefore()` and `.isAfter()`, though. Again, conduct your own benchmarking to determine, but read about benchmarking first, it’s not as straightforward as it may sound.

Comment: To add to other points that it is unwise to pre-optimize programs without knowing whether you have performance issues or not, I want to add, it is unwise to ask as well. There is no way to objectively answer whether x is better than y in terms of performance. Only way to know that will be if you run the Profiler using both and identify it for your program.

Comment: FYI, the implementation of `isBefore` compares the seconds since the epoch. Only if they are equal, it goes on to compare the nanoseconds.